# Is there a practical reason for "#if defined(X) && (X != 0)"?

Tags: preprocessor, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I'm working through some cross platform prerpocessor macros. For Microsoft, I read [the following should be used](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3965645c-978c-4148-b32c-1853f7fd22b3/platform-defined-macros-for-windows-store-app):

```
#if defined(WINAPI_FAMILY) && (WINAPI_FAMILY==WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP)
#   SOME_SETTING_FOR_MY_PROJECT
#endif
```

The point above is an explicit test for `WINAPI_FAMILY` was made before the value was used. (I'm pretty sure an undefined macro evaluates to 0).

For Apple, some of the [samples on their website use](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Lister/Listings/Objective_C_ListerKitTests_AAPLIncompleteListItemsPresenterTests_m.html):

```
#if (TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
#   SOME_SETTING_FOR_MY_PROJECT
#endif
```

The point above is Apple's sample did not use `#if defined(TARGET_OS_IPHONE) && (TARGET_OS_IPHONE != 0)`.

Is one more portable than the other?

Is there a practical reason to use one versus the other? Or is this a matter of style?

**Note**: I'm not really interested in the style of defining some to 0 versus leaving it undefined. If it has practical implications, then I would be interested in insight, though.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is true that an undefined macro default to zero (see [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html)), there is a difference between an undefined macro and a macro that has been purposefully set to zero.

Of course, this does not make too much sense for macros like `WINAPI_FAMILY` because the only valid values for this are 1 and 2. But some macros might have a legitimate meaning behind the value `0` and the meaning might be different to the macro being undefined.

For example, consider a macro for logging levels (`LOG_LEVEL`) that can be assigned to a certain level (`LOG_xxx` macros). And if it is not defined by the user it should default to `LOG_ERROR` (which is 2 and not 0).

```
#define LOG_NONE     0
#define LOG_WARNING  1
#define LOG_ERROR    2
#define LOG_FATAL    3
```

Now, if you only check for the value of `LOG_LEVEL` and it has not been defined by the user or compiler, it will default to `LOG_NONE` instead of `LOG_ERROR`. So in that case you will need the `defined` check as well.

But beyond this, I think that it is more of code style in most cases. I cannot find any C compilers that do not default macro values to zero, so the predominant reason to use `defined` in your case is to stress that this is not just a value check but also considers that the macro might not have been set at all.

**tldr;** Being undefined and being set to zero are not the same thing; but in most cases the use of `defined` is a matter of style or semantic emphasis.